# Inheritable Tracking Decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, decorator, python-decorators

I need a parent class with a decorator defined internally that saves all functions in its class to a list, which is an attribute of the parent class. All children of this class must be able to use the decorator, but storing to a list owned by the specific child.

After numerous attempts at defining such a decorator, I am at a loss for how it would be done. Any help would be greatly appreciated! An example of my preferred usage is shown below.

```
class Parent:
    decorated_functions = []

    # insert decorator definition

class ChildOne(Parent):
    @decorator
    def a(self):
        return 'a'

    @decorator
    def b(self):
        return 'b'

class ChildTwo(Parent):
    @decorator
    def c(self):
        return 'c'

class ChildThree(Parent):
    @decorator
    def d(self):
        return 'd'

    @decorator
    def e(self):
        return 'e'

    @decorator
    def f(self):
        return 'f'

ChildOne().decorated_functions
# [<function __main__.ChildOne.a>, <function __main__.ChildOne.b>]

ChildTwo().decorated_functions
# [<function __main__.ChildTwo.c>]

ChildThree().decorated_functions
# [<function __main__.ChildThree.d>, <function __main__.ChildThree.e>, <function __main__.ChildThree.f>]
```

---

**Update #1**
Using Brendan Abel's metaclass, I have tried using the following code.

```
class Child(Parent):
    @decorator
    def a(self):
        return 'a'

    @decorator
    def b(self):
        return 'b'

print(Child().decorated_functions)
```

However, `Child()` does not seem to have an attribute `decorated_functions`.

```
AttributeError: type object 'Child' has no attribute 'decorated_functions'
```

**Update #2**
The above code now works with Brendan Abel's solution! The issue was a change in syntax for metaclasses Python 3.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work, since at the time the decorator executes, the class doesn't exist yet, so there's nowhere to store the list.  You might be able to do it with a *class* decorator (that is, decorating the class instead of, or in addition to, the methods).  Also, you won't be able to refer to the decorator with a global name like `decorator` if it's defined in a class; you'd have to do `@Parent.decorator`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably won't be able to do this without turning `decorated_functions` into a property (which allows it to be computed after the class has been created), or using a class decorator or metaclasses.  I never thought I'd say this, but a metaclass might be the simplest solution here

```
def decorator(f):
    f.decorated = True
    return f


class DecoMeta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        decorated_functions = []
        for v in attrs.values():
            if getattr(v, 'decorated', None):
                decorated_functions.append(v)
        attrs['decorated_functions'] = decorated_functions
        return super(DecoMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class Parent(object):
    __metaclass__ = DecoMeta
```

Edit:

In Python 3, the metaclass hook is slightly different

```
class Parent(object, metaclass=DecoMeta):
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply!
This seems like it would be the best solution. However, I can't seem to get your code to work. I defined a simple child class (as I showed in my original post), but instances of it do not seem to have an attribute `decorated_functions`.

Comment: Do they inherit from parent class

Comment: Yes. I have put my code as an update in my original post.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.4.

Comment: Ah, python 3 has a different metaclass hook, I'll update the answer